# Get sprite image from ccarray in cocos2dx

Tags: ios, arrays, cocos2d-x

I need to get sprites from ccarray.  am using cocos2dx 2.2.2

For example, i stored around 5 sprites in ccarray when collision detection happens. if(array count >= 1) those sprite image will be available to use as power.
there i need to get first image form array after usage i need to remove form array. so again it will display top most image as power. like this it will go on.

Code for storing in array (Collsion detction)

```
           CCSprite * powersprte = CCSprite::create("Images/Objects/conepower.png");
           PowerArray->addObject(powersprte);
```

now, how to retrive top most image from power array.

Comment: Get last object (http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V2.2/d9/d2e/classcocos2d_1_1_c_c_array.html#a4e2bf15ecdcfbc6de87a6bc3d65109fc), remove last object, and re-insert object at index 0 if you want the array to be a stack. Note that given the CCArray methods it's easier to define that topmost object is the last object in the array rather than the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using this  `CCSprite * sprte = dynamic_cast<CCSprite*>(PowerArray->objectAtIndex(0));`

easily get sprite image from array